# Getting error "Unexpected token <" 304 not modified with express for vue.js library

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

Express server is set up like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');


var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));


app.use('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
});

var port = 3000;

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Express server listening on port", port);
});
```

folder structure:

```
root folder
 dist --- Vue.js
 public --- index.html
 src --- vuejsfiles.js
 server.js
 package.json
 node-modules
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
   <p> This is a vue </p>

  <script src="../dist/vue.js" > </script>
  <script src="../src/vueJS/vuejsfiles.js"> </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting an error "`Unexpected token <`" in the chrome dev console while using `Vue.js` minified file and `vuejsfiles.js`. The error in the console is being pointed at `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the `index.html` file and scripts are not getting parsed. This problem persists only when the server is being run or else if the same file is opened in the browser without server the files are parsed. How to solve this since I want to use a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to somehow expose those folders, just like you are doing with `static/`:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/dist', express.static('dist'));      // added this
app.use('/src/vueJS', express.static('src'));  // added this

// remove the lines below, public is already being served
// app.use('/', function (req, res) {
//    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
// });
```

And use it without `../` in the HTML:

```
<script src="dist/vue.js" > </script>
<script src="src/vueJS/vuejsfiles.js"> </script>
```

Of course, you can use other paths instead of `/dist` and `/src/vueJS`, just remember to update the paths on the HTML files as well.

Comment: using `app.use('/src/vueJS', express.static('src'));` and  `app.use('/dist', express.static('dist')); ` together, still gave me an error for src/vueJS file. So used only `app.use('/dist', express.static('dist')); ` and then created a new folder called minified within dist, moved the minified version inside it and changed the path to `dist/minified/` in html. works. Thank You.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely a better solution!